# how to pinpoint failures inside a loop to a specific value inside a string

Tags: bash, openssl

How do I identify a certificate with a missing or incorrect value when it does not match my requirements?
Ideally if a cert is queried and there was not an answer, I'd like it to print a `-` for the corresponding certificate so I can look into the failure.

I'm creating a list containing specific content of PEM certificate files. The list will contain the CN or email value used in the cert.

To get the CN value I run:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -in certificate.pem | sed -n '/^subject/s/^.*CN=//p'
example.com
```

To get the email value I run:

```
openssl x509 -noout -email -in certificate2.pem
user@example.com
```

I tried this but it is not working as I thought:

```
while read common_names; do
openssl x509 -noout -email -in $common_names
    if [[ -z $common_names ]] ; then
        echo ""$common_names" Not valid smime cert"
    fi
done < /user/audit/smime/smime_list.txt > /user/audit/smime/smime_cert_common_name.txt
```

The contents of /user/audit/smime/smime_list.txt

```
/var/certs/example1.com.crt
/var/certs/example2.com.crt
/var/certs/example3.com.crt
/var/certs/example4.com.crt
/var/certs/example5.com.crt
```

Current broken Output:

```
Cert_Name                         Common_Name                   Days_Expired
examle1.com.crt                   user@examle1.com              30
examle2.com.crt                   user@examle2.com              30
examle3.com.crt     30
examle4.com.crt     30
examle5.com.crt     30
```

Expected and Output without issues:

```
Cert_Name                                 Common_Name                         Days_Expired
example.com.crt                           example.com                         30
```

Expected output with an issue:
exception from a certificate with a missing Common_Name (CN)

```
Cert_Name                                 Common_Name                         Days_Expired
example.com.crt                           -                                   30
```

or

```
Cert_Name                                 Common_Name                         Days_Expired
example.com.crt                           N/A                                 30
```

PS. I already have the days expired from a previous block.

Comment: First try using a different `file descriptor` in read. Then set `IFS=` and then quote all your variables and see where it gets you.

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest this approach? First create list(an array) of certs.

```
certs=(
    certificate1.pem
    certificate2.pem
    certificate3.pem
    # and so on
)
```

or

```
certs=( $(ls /path/*.pem) )
```

And process it

```
XY () { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}"; } # use this function to print in columns

Y=1 # set start Y(lines) to 1 and print 1st row
XY 0 $Y "Cert_Name"; XY 10 $Y "Common_Name"; XY 20 $Y "Days_Expired"
for cert in "${carts[@]}"; {
    ((Y++)) # inc Y to print lines
    common_name=$( code to get Common Name  )
    day_expired=$( code to get Days Expired )
    XY 2 $Y "${cert:-'N/A'}"; XY 12 $Y "${common_name:-'N/A'}"; XY 22 $Y "${day_expired:-'N/A'}"
}
```

Comment: I had to chat carts to certs. When I run this code the cursor jumps back to the top of the screen and starts printing over the existing text in the terminal making it difficult to see what is being printed. Thanks for the guidance. I'm sure it put me on the right path. Will update when I find more

Comment: I got a working array but how do I cater for the described scenario where some certs will be invalid and in those cases it must print a "-" or "N/A" rather than nothing?

Comment: You can set default value like so `echo ${var:-'default_value'}` if var is empty 'default_value' will be echoed.

Answer (score 0):

I used Ivan's suggestion but inside the array I added:

```
common_name=$(openssl x509 -noout -email -in $cert)
   if [[ -z "$common_name" ]] ; then
        common_name="-" 
    fi
```

and

```
day_left=$(/root/server-fixes/ssl-cert-check -b -c $cert  | awk '{print $6}')
    if [[ -z "$day_left" ]] ; then
        day_left="-" 
    fi
```

to set the variable to my desired value if the result is null